# How to dissect business requirements from software requirements in a requirements statement?

Tags: analysis, requirements

I am trying to make a Business Requirements Document and a separate Software Requirements Specifications document. From the following requirements statement, can anyone help me dissect business requirements from software requirements?

Design a system that will maintain positions in real time based on a feed of transactions – buys and sells – that come to the application via MQ.  You should include initial positions loads, fault tolerance and error checking and handling for the process.

Thanks

Comment: Looking closer, it seems like there may be no business requirements here. This is an open ended project, so I think I will have to make assumptions about the business requirements from the software requirements. For example, if the software must maintain trading positions in realtime, I can reasonably assume that the [business] may require this for some sort of risk management, or accounting and extrapolate that the business requirement is to "Monitor trading activity". Does anyone agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the business process for maintaining positions? When does the business need a position? What triggers the need? What steps/tasks maintain a position? When is a position no longer required? Get answers to these questions and you will have business requirements.